# Test quasar q-checkbox is checked using cypress

Tags: cypress, quasar-framework

Cypress say:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="my-checkbox"]')
  .click()
  .should('be.checked')
```

I have also seen elsewhere:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="my-checkbox"]')
  .click()
  .should('have.attr', 'checked')
```

Although the above was actually testing 'not.have.attr', which is probably a weak test as that could mean anything! It does not work in my test.

Using quasar I am unable to use 'check()' as what quasar renders is not a checkbox, but I use 'click()', which does check the box.

The response:

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: expected '<div.q-checkbox.cursor-pointer.no-outline.row.inline.no.wrap.items-center>' to have attribute 'checked'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by @Kuranes is too generic and although it works, it selects too many elements, which is why eq(0) is used in their example.

My question was based on selecting the element to be tested using a data-cy attribute, which is cypress best practice!

However I do owe some thanks to @Kuranes for helping me see what needed to test for.

My working solution is as follows:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="my-checkbox"] .q-checkbox__inner')
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('not.have.class', 'q-checkbox__inner--active')
  .click()
  .should('have.class', 'q-checkbox__inner--active')
```

I am still not completely happy with the solution as the folks at quasar could change their solution on a whim leaving me with broken tests for something that could actually be still working.

Comment: Using or not using data-cy is completely irrelevant to your question and is dependent on personal choice and the way you implement your HTML. Thanks for your honesty

Answer (score 0):

It is apparent that quasar does not use the 'checked' attribute to indicate whether their checkbox is checked or unchecked.

But visiting [Quasar.dev (Vue Checkbox)](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/checkbox) I can see that they use the 'q-checkbox__inner--active' class instead. So you can check for that.
Here is a test you can run against the mentioned website to confirm that this works:

```
it('Unchecks and checks the first checkbox on the quasar demo website', function() {
    cy.visit('https://quasar.dev/vue-components/checkbox')
    cy.get('.q-checkbox').eq(0).click()
    cy.get('.q-checkbox__inner').eq(0).should('not.have.class', 'q-checkbox__inner--active')
    cy.get('.q-checkbox').eq(0).click()
    cy.get('.q-checkbox__inner').eq(0).should('have.class', 'q-checkbox__inner--active')
})
```

In the future, when you are uncertain about how your elements behave or how their attributes change when interacted with, use the developer tools in your browser of choice (F12),  and navigate to the inspector tab:
[image: inspector]

Then you can toggle the first button in the upper left corner (the mouse pointer) to click on elements on the webpage and the inspector will jump to that element in the code.

Next, interact with the element and you can see how it changes in real-time in the code.

Good luck.